# Finding a collection of vectors so that the solution set to the homogeneous equation $Ax =0$ is equal to $\text{Span}\{w_1,\dots , w_p\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

This question appeared on a practice test in my linear algebra course. I don't have any idea at all on how to solve this, and was hoping someone could give me a detailed solution, and a short explanation on how/why it works. Thank you so much!

> **Question:** Find a collection of vectors $w_1,\dots,w_p$ (however many it takes) so that the solution set to the homogeneous equation $Ax=0$ is equal to $\text{Span}\{w_1,\dots,w_p\}$, where:
>   $$A=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-4&0&-4\\2&-8&0&8\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

You wish to determine which vectors are sent to zero by this matrix $A$:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}-1&-4&0&-4\\2&-8&0&8\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-a-4b-4d\\2a-8b+8d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
Then adding two of the first of the equations we obtained to the second, we see that $-16b=0\implies b=0$ and from the first, hence $a=-4d$.

So the nullspace (which they wanted you to calculate) has a basis $$\text{Basis}(\text{N}(A))=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}-4d\\0\\0\\d\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\c\\0\end{bmatrix}\right\}=\{w_1,w_2\}$$
They worded it as if you haven't yet defined a basis, which is odd, so any linear combination of these vectors could be added to that collection.

$$N(A)=\{\alpha w_1 + \beta w_2: \alpha,\beta\in \Bbb F\} \quad (\Bbb{F}=\Bbb{C} \text{ or } \Bbb F=\Bbb R \text{ most likely })$$